# Error attribute has already been defined

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock

i know this question have been asked a lot..but I can't resolve this problem.I'm a newbie, help me.
So, there are code in my gradle build:

```
        dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
        compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.7.jar')
    }
```

and this is my error:

```
    Error:(160) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
    Error:(14) Original attribute defined here.
    Error:(197) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
    Error:(160) Original attribute defined here.
    Error:(197) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
    Error:(160) Original attribute defined here.
    Error:(212) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" already defined with incompatible format.
    Error:(206) Original attribute defined here.
    Error:(212) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" already defined with incompatible format.
    Error:(206) Original attribute defined here.
    Error:(212) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
    Error:(206) Original attribute defined here.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Truc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following these steps:

1. Put .jar file into the libs folder.
2. Right click on it and click 'Add as Library'.
3. Add this line **compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.7.jar')** or this line if you have more than one .jar file : **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')**.
4. Do a clean build.

This method worked for me.

Comment: Thanks you, I tried do this, but it don't work for me. I think this error appeared because actionbarsherlock but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is it compulsory for you to use actionbarsherlock? You can use AppCompat for a more up to date action bar. Take a look : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html